# jQuery add inlline CSS into html raw content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `string` variable with html element.

```
var myvar = '<p>Hi, ##CandidateName## and this is your ##CandidateEmail##</p>';
```

How can I add some inline styles to text between `##`. I can't modify source content so I must use `##`

Comment: You can't add CSS to words inside a node. You can only apply it to elements. As such I'd suggest wrapping the `##` sections in `<span>` elements and applying the CSS/a class to them

Comment: var myvar = "<p>Hi, ##CandidateName## and this is your ##CandidateEmail##</p>"; This is my html I want to add some css in this html where text with ##....## only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use some tag instead of `##` - for example `span`. Then you can use `find()` function to find your elements.

---

### Exmaple

If you can't modify original text than you can use `replace()` function with regular expression to replace `##` with for example `span` and then apply styles for each `span` of your element.

```js
// your element in string
var myvar = '<p>Hi, ##CandidateName## and this is your ##CandidateEmail##</p>';

// replace ## with <span></span>
myvar = myvar.replace(/\##(.*?)\##/g, "<span>$1</span>");

// introduce it as a jQuery element
var $myvar = $(myvar);

// find <span> in your element and apply styles
$myvar.find('span').css({'color':"pink"});

// place it somewhere
$('#someDiv').append($myvar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=someDiv></div>
```

Comment: But I must use ##. Is there any another way possible?

Comment: I've provided example with `##`. I've used `replace()` function with regular expression which replace `##` by `span` and then colored it with `css()` function

Comment: Is there any possible to find span tag without id or class. Because in that raw html I didn't have any class or id. Please help

Comment: Well, what are you going to do with the final element? For example: I've appended it into the `<div id=someDiv>` so I could find it by `$('#someDiv').find('span')` too (or any other element or id). Specify your situation and I'll try to. Are you going to append it somewhere or something like that?

Comment: I've provided example without ID selector.

Comment: I get that html from CKEDITOR content. In that raw html there is no Id or Class. Content should be raw html with p tag only. After changing the color I want to show that html inside a popup.

Comment: Modified and described my answer. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Its working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

You can take dynamic data in a variable first.

`var name = ##CandidateName##;
 var email = ##CandidateEmail##;
 var myvar = '<p>Hi, <span>'+name+'</span> and this is your <span>'+ email 
 +'</span></p>';`